# when project needs reference to other dlls

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, generics, .net-assembly

I encountered strange behavior and don't know the reason. I have two projects A and B. A references System.Web assembly and B references A. I add using statement to projects B class `using A`. It works fine until I start using linq statements. **I get compilation error**:

```
The type 'System.Web.UI.Control' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Simplified example project. Two projects Parent and Child. Parent project references System.Web. Child project references Parent project.
Parent project contains one class Parent:

```
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Parent
{
    public static class Parent
    {
        public static T DoStuff<T>(this object obj)
            where T : Control 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Child project contains one class Child:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Parent;

namespace Child
{
    public class Child
    {
        void Test()
        {
            var strings = new List<string>();
            var string1 = strings.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown on `var string1 = strings.First();`. I would just add reference to System.Web in Child project and everything works fine. But I would like to understand why it works like this.
If I change parent class to:

```
public static class Parent
{
    public static Control DoStuff(this object obj)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Instead of using generics I use Control class directly. And it works fine.
Any ideas?

edited: `var string1 = strings.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

If you reference a project, it adds a reference to its compiled dll.
However, only because you reference a dll doesn't makes your project to reference recursively all dll's that are referenced by the referenced dll.

Let's say you add a reference to project B to your project A. While project B has a reference to `System.Web` it won't automatically reference it in project A.
If the system would recursively add references to a dll you would end up having a ton of references you don't need.

That is why you still have to reference all necessary assemblies **manually** in your project A in order to be able to use everything from Project B.

Comment: ok. But what I do not understand is. 1) I do not use DoStuff method. 2) Why it failse on linq statements only (at least if I don't use the it compiles) 3) why it doesn't work only if Control is defined in generic's where clause and works when Control is parameter of method or return type of method.

Comment: I'm just speculating now. However I think this could be because FirstOrDefault() is an extension method. Maybe when you call it starts searching for all extension methods in all loaded assemblies. When he comes across your static class "Parent" (Extensions are also in a static class) he starts searching your class for extensions methods and comes across the System.Web.UI.Controls class where he then fails to resolve that class. However this is just speculating as I am not sure what causes that line to throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: I want to emphasize that it is compile time error not runtime